# Show interactive list of files changed by commit in vim-fugitive

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I use the fugitive status windows quite a lot when working on commits. It's an easy and interactive way to see what I have changed and I can open any of the files where I have made changes and e.g. diff them. However, after I have committed, I can't find an equally great way to browse files changed at a specific commit or a commit interval. Ideally what I want is something like the fugitive status windows, but the most important feature is a list of files where I can click on a file and have it open.

#### Things I have tried

- Opening the commit object. This has two issues:

  1. It shows the diffs between the files so navigating to a file to open takes a while.
  2. If I click a file it opens in the current window, so quickly jumping between files doesn't work.
- `Gclog --name-only` Gets my list of files, but it isn't interactive.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Is this generally what one should do? I'm never really sure whether one should ask questions as issues in their repo or ask on stack overflow when a tag with a reasonable number of questions exists.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow is a programming Q/A site so, in general, questions that don't involve programming are OT. Now, Vim questions (as well as Git questions and other topics tightly related to programming) have been in a sort of grey area since the beginning of SO so there is a rather large "Vim" tag and "Vim" questions have a reasonably high chance of being answered but…

Comment: … there are two schools of thought about help-seeking strategies. One school prefers to start from a global/generic context (web search, generic sites like SO, etc.) and drill down to the local/specific if necessary (doc, specific support channel, maintainer, etc.) while the other school prefers to do it the other way around, from the local/specific to the global/generic. I'm firmly in the second school, hence my recommendation: no one has a better domain expertise than the author of the plugin.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll take it to the repo then and come back and answer here if I get one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question in the repository and got an answer by the creator.

[[Question] Browse files changed by a commit](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1773)

The author of the plugin said that it is their long term goal to make the commit objects look and behave like the summary window. However, until that is implemented I can achieve a workflow similar to my request by

1. Opening the commit object but with foldmethod set to `syntax`. This will fold the diffs and have each file on a separate line. Can also use `[m` and `]m` to move the cursor between files in the commit object.
2. Open files by pressing <kbd>o</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this will open them in a split and not the current window.

Comment: And press "O" to open the file in a new tab!